# Creating an array of search strings without redundance in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Given an array that gets populated with strings. I need following behavior:

```
foo = []
foo = add_search_string(foo, 'a')
```

foo should equal ['a']

```
foo = add_search_string(foo, 'a')
```

foo should equal ['a'] because 'a' was already a search string

```
foo = add_search_string(foo, 'ab')
```

foo should equal ['ab'] because 'a' is a substring of 'ab' and therefore can be removed

```
foo = add_search_string(foo, 'a')
```

foo should equal ['ab'] because of the same reason as above

```
foo = add_search_string(foo, 'c')
```

foo should equal ['ab', 'c']

My function looks like this:

```
function add_search_string(search_strings, new_search_string) {
    var keep = true;
    var new_search_strings = []
    $.each(search_strings, function(i, search_string) {
        if (new_search_string == search_string) {
            keep = false;
        } else if (search_string.indexOf(new_search_string) >= 0) {
            keep = false;
        }
    });

    if (keep) {
        $.each(search_strings, function(i, search_string) {
            if (new_search_string.indexOf(search_string) == -1) {
                new_search_strings.push(search_string);
            }
        });
        new_search_strings.push(new_search_string);
        search_strings = new_search_strings;
    }
    return search_strings;
}
```

Is there a 'better' way to do this?

Comment: Is `"b"` a substring of `"ab"` for this purpose? Or is it more about "starts with"?

Comment: 'b' would be a substring of 'ab'. For an array that already contains 'ab', adding the search string 'b' would also result in ['ab']

Comment: So if `foo = ['ab']` and we then use `foo = add_search_string(foo, 'def')` should `foo` now equal `abdef` or `def`?

Comment: So as per Bergi's comment below `add_search_string(['a','b'], 'abc')` should return `['abc']` (combining the multiple matches)?

Comment: 'a' is a substring of 'ab' and therefore can be removed => because your purpose is to do an AND search? (result must match all strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to keep updating the same array I'd probably do something like this:

```
function add_search_string(search_strings, new_search_string) {
   var replaced = false;
   for (var i = search_strings.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (search_strings[i].indexOf(new_search_string) != -1) {
          // string found, so just return
          return search_strings;
      }
      if (new_search_string.indexOf(search_strings[i]) != -1){
          // existing string is a substring of new search string
          // if it already matched another element just remove the current one
          // otherwise replace the current one
          if (replaced)
              search_strings.splice(i,1);
          else
              search_strings[i] = new_search_string;
          replaced = true;
      }
   }
   // if not found add it
   if (!replaced)
      search_strings.push(new_search_string);
   return search_strings;
}
```

Although this function returns the array, it also updates the array you pass in so you don't have to assign it back when you call the function, you can just say:

```
add_search_string(foo, 'a');
```

Comment: The second condition must not break, think about `add(['d', 'f'], 'def')`

Comment: Good point @Bergi, I didn't think about a string overlapping more than one element.

Comment: exactly `add(['d', 'f'], 'def')` should result in `['def']`

Comment: OK, answer updated to allow for that. (I hope.) If new string is a substring of existing element just return, as I was originally doing, but if existing elements are substrings of new string replace one of them and remove the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a fast built in way to do this. And if you want to test for true substrings and not just 'starts with' it's a quadratic problem meaning that the function will take n^2 times as long with n the length of the key. If the keys are not too long it should work though.

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted to prevent.

Comment: Well in the example @nnnnnn uses it is actually a N*M problem. With N the length of the new key and M the number of existing keys. :)

Comment: but he is not checking the other way arround... the case where a new search string makes old search strings obsolete

Answer (score 1):

As you need a "contain" operator, an array join() could be efficient:

```
var str = search_strings.join("|");

// if the new string can't be found
if str.indexOf(new_search_string)==-1 {
    // remove sub-strings of new_search_string (need to start from the top)
    for (var i=search_strings.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if (new_search_string.indexOf(search_strings[i])!=-1) {search_strings.splice(i,1);}
    }
    // add new
    search_strings.push(new_search_string);
}
// else new_search_string can be ignored
```

For faster processing, you might also consider ordering or filtering your array by string length, and only looping through the strings that are shorter than new_search_string.

Answer (score 0):

For a performant implementation, you would use a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) to search quickly amongst your search strings (and their subsets). However, you should do that only if you really face problems with a simple implementation (like yours or @nnnnnn's one), as a trie would add a huge complexity layer.